# Error when Returning std::string from a function with return type of user defined String class

Tags: c++, string

I have defined my own string class in "String.cpp" (class `String`), in some function with return type `String`, i am trying to return `std::string`, but it throws error Error:

```
Cannot use std::string  to initialize PiaStd::String
```

Please help

```
String System::getHostName()
{
    // in between code
    std::string result;
    struct addrinfo* p;
    for(p = ppResult; p != 0; p=p->ai_next)
    {
        result += std::string(p->ai_canonname);
    }
    Freeaddrinfo(ppResult);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry your function signature returns your class `String` but you're returning a `std:string` where is the conversion taking place?

Comment: @EdChum Unless they have an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `String` available, but they would likely know if they made such a method.

Comment: @CoryKramer indeed, but there is insufficient code being shown here to show whether this is an oversight or an error on the OP's implementation of their String class to provide the method to instantiate/construct their `String` class from a `std::string`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler does not know how to make your string from `std::string`. You need to provide a way to do it by writing one of the following:

- Create a constructor of `PiaStd::String` that takes `const std::string&` as a parameter, or
- Create a custom conversion operator from `std::string` to `PiaStd::String`

You could also change `getHostName()` to make your custom string, or to return `std::string`.